# Call Child component's field validation method when clicking Next/Submit

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a parent page component which contains multiple child components to make up a dynamic Form.  One of these child components is Address, which contains all the normal fields for a residential address.  When I click 'Next' on the page component, I want the Address component to call it's `validateAddress` method before allowing the rest of the functionality.  I am passing a setAllAddressInputsValid state boolean down to the Address component so it can return that it's either valid or invalid(and has its own error handling). The parent code is below:

```
const xxxPage = () => {

  const [allAddressInputsValid, setAllAddressInputsValid] = React.useState(false);

  const handleNext = () => {
    **Call validation for Address here, which sets allAddressInputsValid in state**
    if (allAddressInputsValid) {
      history.push('next-page');
    }
  };

  return (
    <Form id="xxx">
      <FieldGroup
        isFull
        labelStyle="h3-light"
        labelVisual="xxx"
      >
        <... not relevant ...
          >
            <Address
              fieldName="xxx"
              labelVisual="xxx"
              setAllAddressInputsValid={setAllAddressInputsValid}
            />
            <... not relevant ...
             >
      </FieldGroup>
      <PageNavigation
        onNext={handleNext}
        primaryButtonText="Next"
      />
    </Form>
  );
};

export default xxxPage;
```

The only relevant code from the Address component is the `validateAddress` method

```
const validateAddress = () => {
    const errors = *calls another method*

    if (errors.length > 0) {
      setAllAddressInputsValid(false);
      *error handling*
    } else {
      setAllAddressInputsValid(true);
    }
  };
```

How can I get the `handleNext` function in the parent component to call this `validateAddress` in the child?

Comment: Why don't you move the `handleNext` function from the child to the parent?

Comment: @GabrielPichot `handleNext` is in the parent.  But I want it to call the child's self-validation function

Comment: Instead of calling child component method keep track of address validation in child component and send it to Parent Component so that when you click next you have the validation information